# service for fdm

Tags: download

what is the service for free download manager. I think its still running in the background even if I'm not opening it. And I think it also consumes my bandwidth. What the service?so that I could stop it on services.msc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it does not run as a service, it runs as an application and places an icon in the system tray.

If you want to see what is using your bandwidth consider installing a bandwidth manager/network/monitor.